# Pepper Plants - Strange Spots and Colouration

Tags: diagnosis, vegetables, indoors, peppers

Pictures should speak for themselves.

6 Week old pepper plants started from seeds.
Are they doing okay? I keep them inside under LED lights. Whats with the purpley colour?
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What variety of peppers are these? Some varieties have purple coloration of the leaves. Where the seeds storebought or did you harvest them from other peppers?

Comment: Storebought bell peppers.